# How to avoid 4 core limit for Ubuntu within VMWare?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware, limit

I have Ubuntu installed as VM on my laptop. My laptop has quad core with HT technology making it 8 cores.

Within Ubuntu VM I can only use max of 4 cores.

What should I do so I can access all 8?

Which Linux distribution would let me use all my cores? Which VM software should I use?

Any advices?

Comment: "HP" Technology?  Maybe you mean Hyper Threading?

Comment: @psusi, you're absolutely correct.

Comment: Well, I don't think Ubuntu has such limitation; in VirtualBox I successfully gave 8 cores to a VM. Do you see the 8 cores on the host OS?

Comment: @Renan, yes, task manages within Windows 8 as my host shows 8 cores. In VMWare System monitor shows 4 cores. When in settings I try to add more than 4 cores it tells me "The virtual machine is configured to run with 6 CPUs, but VMware Player supports only up to 4 CPUs.". So virtual box doesn't have such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [hitting a VMware Player limitation](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/).

> VMware Player takes advantage of the latest hardware to create virtual machines with up to 4 virtual processors, 2 TB virtual disks and up to 64 GB of memory per virtual machines.

VirtualBox has a much higher limit ([32](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30404), as far as I can tell).